# SQL Server select variable where no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I set variables if the query returns no results?

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Output = 'Old';
SELECT @Output = 'New' WHERE 0 = 1;

PRINT @Output;
```

Output value is: **Old**

Expected value is: **NULL**

Comment: Why do you expect it to be null?  The 0=1 is false, so it's not going to set the variable at all.

Comment: A query that returns no rows does not return `NULL`, it returns no rows. If you aren't passing a value (including `NULL`) to the assignment, then the variable won't be updated, no value was passed to assign it. `NULL` is not the absence of a value, it is an unknown value; which is still a value.

Comment: You could check the value of `@@RowCount` after the second `select` to determine if a row was processed. It will be zero in this case.

Comment: You are now experiencing the difference between using SELECT and SET to assign a variable. Had you used SET, the variable would be NULL after the SET statement executes. SELECT has the side effect of **NOT** changing the variable if no rows are selected.

Comment: For others who arrived here for a subtly different but related question, if you remove line two from the poster's question (SELECT @Output = 'Old';) then the value is null because it remains in its initialized state; "The DECLARE statement initializes a Transact-SQL variable by...Setting the value to NULL"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Output = 'Old';
SELECT @Output = 'New' WHERE 0 = 1;
PRINT @Output;
```

You get `'Old'` cause the variable already has this value, and it will not update the value since in the `WHERE` clause you use the condition `0=1`, which will return `FALSE` and the value in the variable won't change.

`WHERE 0 = 1` It will be False

`WHERE 0 <> 1` It will be True

It's just similar to `IF 0=1 THEN UpdateMyVar`

So in your case the value will always `'Old'`, it won't return `'New'` or `NULL` either.

I don't know what are you trying to do really, but if you want to return `NULL` then

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Output = 'Old';
SELECT @Output = NULL WHERE 0 <> 1; --If 0<> 1 then update my var and set NULL else leave it as it is
PRINT @Output;
```

Comment: My Where condition is set to false because I need to simulate a query that returns no result. There are side other effects in my context if I change my where condition. So, I need to alter the variable on an empty resultset.

Comment: @profimedica - you can't in the `SELECT` if the resultset is empty. You can check `@@ROWCOUNT` immediately after and do something there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Output = 'Old';
SELECT @Output = CASE 0 WHEN 1 THEN 'New' ELSE NULL END
SELECT @Output;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the op.

Comment: Your switch case works always on false branch. It is a valid syntax but my code was isolated from a complex procedure where the WHERE condition has multiple conditions. For readability I simplified it in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sami provides a good explanation of what is going on.

If you want to be sure that a value is assigned, then you need to be sure that the query returns one row for the assignment.  One way to do this is to use aggregations:

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Output = 'Old';
SELECT @Output = MAX('New') WHERE 0 = 1;
SELECT @Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how assigning variables in `SELECT` is implemented in SQL Server. As @SMor said in the comments, use [`SET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `SELECT`.

```
DECLARE @Output AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Output = 'Old';
SET @Output = (SELECT 'New' WHERE 0 = 1);
-- this would change the @Output value to NULL

SELECT @Output;
```

The only problem with `SET` is that it can assign only one variable, while in `SELECT` you can assign many variables at the same time.